# Save Email as .MSG to Local Folder using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created a rule to move emails from inbox to subfolder "Task" .I am able to move the all emails from subfolder "Task" to another subfolder "Complete" in outlook but can anyone assist me in copying the emails as .msg file locally to a pre-defined folder.Below is the powershell code.

```
$olFolderInbox = 6;
$GetOutlook = New-Object -com "Outlook.Application";
$olName = $GetOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$olxEmailFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

$SubFolders = $olxEmailFolder.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Tasks' };
$TargetFolder = $olxEmailFolder.Folders.Item('Completed')

$SubFolders.Items |

ForEach-Object -Process {
$psitem.Move($TargetFolder)


}
```

Comment: Hi, check this : https://powershell.org/forums/topic/save-msg-file-from-outlook/ and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532393/save-email-as-msg-file-without-using-outlook-com-object-etc-or-3rd-party-sof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure if you can save an email to a .msg, however, you can save it as a .htm using the modified code

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
Add-Type -assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook'
$GetOutlook = New-Object -ComObject 'Outlook.Application'
$olName = $GetOutlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$olxEmailFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

$SubFolders = $olxEmailFolder.Folders | Where-Object -FilterScript {
  $_.Name -match 'Tasks' 
}
$TargetFolder = $olxEmailFolder.Folders.Item('Completed')

$SubFolders.Items |    
ForEach-Object -Process {
  $psitem.HTMLBody | Set-Content C:\test\email.htm
  $psitem.Move($TargetFolder)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hitesh for the alternative solution. But I want to Save the Emails with the subject line.How can we make this possible.Is it like as mentioned below

Comment: `$filename = $psitem.TaskSubject 
      $psitem.HTMLBody | Set-Content      C:\Users\vijay.jadpalsukumar\Documents\Test\$filename.htm`

Comment: This modification will save the emails with the **Subject** as the filename
`ForEach-Object -Process {
  $filename = $psitem.Subject
  $psitem.HTMLBody | Set-Content "C:\test\$filename.htm"
  $psitem.Move($TargetFolder)
}`

Comment: Hi Hitesh, Its Saving as "File" with file size of 0KB and not as an HTML file.Can you please check and assist further.

Comment: @Vijay, please verify that you have e-mails available in the **Tasks** folder, and you have some content in the email's body.

Comment: Actually the mail subject included many special characters and space.I had to fine tune the filename.Below changes made things work.Thanks for your prompt response and solution.

Comment: `ForEach-Object -Process {
  $filename = $psitem.Subject
  $pattern = '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]'
  $filename1 = $filename.ToString() -replace(" ","_")
  $filename2 = $filename1 -replace $pattern
  $psitem.HTMLBody | Set-Content "C:\Temp\$filename2.html"
  $psitem.Move($TargetFolder)
}`