# convert msg to html without using outlook in powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, outlook-redemption, msg

I want to convert msg files (in the local folder) to html in powershell. I have done this by using outlook but the problem is this script will work on server so I cant use outlook.
So far, I have searched these questions:

- [Save Email as MSG file without using Outlook (COM object, etc.) or 3rd party software](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26532393/10389562)
- [convert msg to html in background using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945024/convert-msg-to-html-in-background-using-vbscript)
- [Read Outlook .msg File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633082/read-outlook-msg-file)

I couldnt find many approaches with Powershell. However, with the help of the questions above I downloaded Redemption and used it like this:

```
$routlook = New-Object -COM Redemption.RDOSession
$routlook.Logon()
$msg = $routlook.GetMessageFromMsgFile("C:\temp\test.msg",$TRUE)
$path = "C:\temp\test.html"
$msg.HTMLBody | Set-Content $path
```

But $msg.HTMLBody just returns an empty html in the below and $msg.Body returns nothing:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/plain format -->
</BODY></HTML>
```

Probably I am using Redemption in a wrong way and dont know how to fix it. Or is there any other 3rd party solution that can be used in servers rather than using outlook?

Thanks for any help

Comment: are we talking a outlook msg file?

Comment: Yes, I am trying this for outlook msg files.

Comment: are you just trying to recover text or what ?

Comment: You can find the MS-OXMSG standards here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912.aspx)

Comment: I am trying to get mail's body content and convert it to an html file. $msg.HTMLBody creates an html file, as I wanted, but with nothing in the body section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter when you call `GetMessageFromMsgFile` is true, which means you are creating a brand new file. Pass false instead.

Also note that `GetMessageFromMsgFile` does not require an active session, so there is no need to call `RDOSession.Logon`. And there won't be a profile if you are running under a service user anyway.

To create an HTML file, you don't need to read the `RDOMail.HTMLBody` property. You can call `RDOMail.SaveAs(..., olHTML)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but the html file that has been created doesnt have any html tags and includes only this kind of things:
ÐÏà¡±á 
   
   ÿÿÿÿ

Comment: I just checked it and found out that it was my mistake, I had passed invalid variant for olHTML. Sorry for that, it works with your solution as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the **$TRUE** parameter:

```
$routlook = New-Object -COM Redemption.RDOSession
$routlook.Logon()
$msg = $routlook.GetMessageFromMsgFile("C:\temp\test.msg")
$path = "C:\temp\test.html"
$msg.HTMLBody | Set-Content $path
```

And you can open your msg file and after that, save as html

Comment: Yes, that helped a lot ! It created a proper html file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear, it worked fine with both answers and my complete code for either ways:

```
$routlook = New-Object -COM Redemption.RDOSession
$location = "C:\temp\Redemption\"
$msg = $routlook.GetMessageFromMsgFile("C:\temp\test.msg",$FALSE)
$name = "test.html"
$path = $location + $name
$msg.SaveAs($path,5)
```

Or

```
$routlook = New-Object -COM Redemption.RDOSession
$location = "C:\temp\Redemption\"
$msg = $routlook.GetMessageFromMsgFile("C:\temp\test.msg")
$name = $_.Name + ".html"
$path = $location + $name
$msg.HTMLBody | Set-Content $path
```